# issue with overriding .equals() method

Tags: java, junit, overriding

I was working on overriding .equals() in java for an "Item" class with a Constructor in the form of:

```
public Item(final String theName, final BigDecimal thePrice, final int theBulkQuantity,
            final BigDecimal theBulkPrice) {
    myName = Objects.requireNonNull(theName);
    myPrice = Objects.requireNonNull(thePrice);
    myBulkQuantity = theBulkQuantity;
    myBulkPrice = theBulkPrice;

}
```

using this .equals method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object theOther) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (this == theOther) {
        result = true;
    }
    else if (theOther != null && theOther == this.getClass()) {
        final Item other = (Item) theOther;

        if ((this.myName.equals(other.myName)) 
            && (this.myBulkQuantity == other.myBulkQuantity)            
            && (this.myPrice.equals(other.myPrice))
            && (this.myBulkPrice.equals(other.myBulkPrice))) {
            result = true;
        }                        
    }    
    return result;
}
```

I'm a new Computer Science student and this is my first attempt at overriding. I would have overlooked this if I had not used JUnit testing using the following:

```
testItemB = new Item("ItemB", new BigDecimal("5.00"), 5, new BigDecimal("20.00"));
testItemC = new Item("ItemB", new BigDecimal("5.00"), 5, new BigDecimal("20.00"));
```

and got an assertion error saying that they weren't equivalent. At first glance I am pretty sure that I got everything but do you guys happen to see anything glaring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `equals()` method you compared the object instance `theOther` with `this.getClass()` which will always return false since your are comparing an instance with a class type.

Depending on your use case, you may use

```
obj1.getClass().equals(obj2.getClass())
```

or

```
theOther instanceof Item
```

Comment: Beat me to it :)  Good answer.

Comment: @Dinesh I see the problem. Although I instead replaced `theOther` with `theOther.getClass()` which seemed to make it work. Hopefully it isn't a fluke.